# Zendfox installation: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'zendfox.zf_core_module' doesn't exist

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I again tried to install fresh zendfox but error occurred:
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'zendfox.zf_core_module' doesn't exist

Comment: Have you exported the database into your system.?

Comment: yes i have exported DB into the localhost

Comment: then check whether the table `zf_core_module` exists in database `zendfox` and your are connected with the same database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were errors with DB. I dropped the DB. created a new one and it worked